# Error in PutDatabasrRecord-Controller Service State is currently ENABLING

Tags: apache, apache-nifi

I have a flow to ingest data into MySQl table but I am getting the error( as attached in screenshot)

Can anyone help me with what kind of error it is? I fail to understand how to fix this.
Attaching the config for PutDatabseRecord:

[image: PutDatabaseRecord Configs]

[image]

Comment: The `DBCPConnectionPool` controller service hasn't properly enabled the connection. You can see where it is failing by navigating to the ControllerService page (by clicking the -> arrow in your first screenshot) and in the left most column, you would see a note/warning icon. Hover over that icon to read the message. You can also read that from nifi-app.log

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman I checked The DBCPConnection pool is Enabled and shows no error on clicking the arrow. Any suggestion?

Comment: Go through the `nifi-app.log` and check if anything is fishy there.

Comment: are u running this in a docker container? can you see error message in the top right corner , below hamburger sign?